# Prepare igraph input data by making id starting from one

Tags: r, igraph

I have a database with three columns, the first two represents the ID of the vertex of a graph, whereas the third one represent the distance between them.

```
cbind(id1=c(10,10,30,12,400,30),id2=c(11,12,400,30,10,79),dist=c(1000,20000,30123,1233,20200,400))

      id1 id2  dist
[1,]  10  11  1000
[2,]  10  12 20000
[3,]  30  400 30123
[4,]  12  30  1233
[5,]  400 10 20200
[6,]  30  79   400
```

In order for igraph package to read such data, vertex ids need to be consecutive and starting with one. So something like this:

```
    id1 id2  dist
[1,]  1  2  1000
[2,]  1  3 20000
[3,]  4  5 30123
[4,]  3  4  1233
[5,]  5  1 20200
[6,]  4  6   400
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to do it automatically? 
In addition, I would also like to create conversion table with both the original and the new name for the ids:

```
    old_id new_id
[1,]    1    1
[2,]   11    2
[3,]   12    3
[4,]   30    4
[5,]  400    5
[6,]   79    6
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order for igraph package to read such data, vertex ids need to be consecutive and starting with one.

That's actually not completely true, you can use symbolic ids:

```
library(igraph)

mat <- cbind(id1 =c(10,  10,   30,   12,  400,  30),
             id2 =c(11,  12,   400,  30,  10,   79),
             dist=c(1000,20000,30123,1233,20200,400))
g <- graph.data.frame(as.data.frame(mat))

g
# IGRAPH DN-- 6 6 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), dist (e/n)

V(g)$name
# [1] "10"  "30"  "12"  "400" "11"  "79" 

str(g)
# IGRAPH DN-- 6 6 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), dist (e/n)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] 10 ->11  10 ->12  30 ->400 12 ->30  400->10  30 ->79
```

Comment: Much easier indeed :) I missed this basic function! Thanks